# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return in Chrome console

Tags: javascript

Stupid question, but why does:

```
function anymal(){var a=3, return a}
VM215:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
```

return that Uncaught syntaxError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `(var|let|const) variableName variableValue,`, *with that trailing comma*, the interpreter takes that to mean that you're preparing to declare another variable. For example:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;
```

is shorthand for

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
```

But `return` cannot be a variable name - it is a reserved word, so when the interpreter sees your `var a = 3, return ...`, it cannot create a variable named `return`, and throws a `SyntaxError`

If you actually wanted to return `a` at that point, use a semicolon, not a comma:

```
var a = 3;
return a;
```